# How do I deposit and restore my Ethereum to my wallet?

Tags: web3js

I want Ethereum to enter my Metamask wallet and I can use it easily to this address. 0x005449873eFD4b886DFDb3dfFeB1fA93817F8449

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your account into MetaMask. Read [this guide](https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360015489331-How-to-import-an-account) on how to.

Comment: Gabriel, thank you, can you guide me more, I can use my assets, I think you know well, the money has been credited to my account, my country does not allow me to use it and has blocked all my documents and cards, please guide me, thank you؟؟

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Once you have the crypto assets stored on your wallet address, you can use any fiat off-ramp providers, such as [Transak](https://global.transak.com/) to sell any amount.

Comment: فیات رو به چه صورت استفاده کنم کارت بانکی مستر من غیر فعال هستش

Comment: Gabriel, please help me to enter my account into the Metamask wallet and use my assets, because I don't have a bank card that I can use. The banker that I introduced did not send me my Bamki card and I could not use my account. Please help me. Thank you.